# psql - Retrieving json data that contains special characters

Tags: json, psql

It looks like my psql DB contains some badly formatted json fields, hence I cannot retrieve this data using ->> operators.

I have a table with column "reputation" of type json.

I perform query to get "reputation" column for a specific object:

```
select reputation from hashes where sha1='c1b5684e132a85d18a35ddb98233cc2b71efcf0e'
```

I receive the following result which looks like json formatted with escape characters:

```
"{\"status\": \"MALICIOUS\", \"scanner_match\": 33, \"first_seen\": \"2010-05-27T09:00:27\", \"scanner_count\": 34, \"last_seen\": \"2010-05-27T09:00:27\"}"
```

However, when I'm trying to get a specific field in this json, I receive nothing:

```
select reputation->>status from hashes where sha1='c1b5684e132a85d18a35ddb98233cc2b71efcf0e'
```

I also tried the following query to check how psql handles this json and received error:

```
select * from json_each((select reputation from hashes where sha1='c1b5684e132a85d18a35ddb98233cc2b71efcf0e'));
ERROR:  cannot deconstruct a scalar
```

So it looks like psql does not recognize this as json. If so, I have a couple of questions:

1. If this is invalid json format, then how is it possible that psql allows us to insert badly formatted json to json type column?
2. Is it possible somehow to access these json fields in the existing state (maybe using some special characters in the names)?

Answer (score 1):

its the backslashes. Psql will see them as escape characters and insert into a json data type with no problem.

View in sql the string is seen as a string and not json, you need to perform some string functions to remove the erroneous characters.

```
with cte as(
select cast ('"{\"status\": \"MALICIOUS\", \"scanner_match\": 33, \"first_seen\": \"2010-05-27T09:00:27\", \"scanner_count\": 34, \"last_seen\": \"2010-05-27T09:00:27\"}"'as json)  as string)

select cast(ltrim(rtrim(replace(cast(string as text),'\',''),'"'),'"')as json)
from cte
```

This returns a json datatype